# Why am I loosing bytes in file transfer through sockets in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to seng a file (in this case a jpg file) from client to server through a socket, but I am loosing some bytes in the process.

I am able to send an image and it looks identical to an original one and has the same resolution, but it is smaller in bytes. Original: 145018 bytes. Received: 139264. First I am sending a header, which contains a file name and a file size, when the server receives the header it sends a message back to client: "Header received", after that client sends the file to the server and server saves the file into `f'received/{fileName}'`

**Server**

```py
import socket
import argparse
import os
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("address", help='IP address of the host')
parser.add_argument("port", type=int, help='Portnumber of the host')

HEADERSIZE = 10

def main():

    args = parser.parse_args()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((args.address, args.port))
    sock.listen(5)
    (client, addr) = sock.accept()
    fileSizeAndName = client.recv(128)
    if(fileSizeAndName):
        print("Received a connection from ", addr)
        fileSize = int(fileSizeAndName[:HEADERSIZE])
        fileName = str(fileSizeAndName[HEADERSIZE:], "utf-8")
        print(f'Incoming file: {fileName}, size: {fileSize} bytes')
        client.sendall(bytes("Header received", "utf-8"))
        bSize = 0
        print("Received a connection from ", addr)
        f = open(f'received\{fileName}','wb')
        #received_bytes = bytearray(client.recv(2048))
        while True:
            f.write(client.recv(2048))
            bSize += 2048
            if bSize > fileSize:
                sock.close()
                client.close()
                sys.exit(str(os.path.getsize(f'received\{fileName}')) + ' bytes')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Client**

```py
import socket
import argparse

HEADERSIZE = 10

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename')
parser.add_argument("address", help='IP address of the host')
parser.add_argument("port", type=int, help='Portnumber of the host')
args = parser.parse_args()

filename = args.filename.split('/')[len(args.filename.split('/')) - 1]

with open(args.filename, 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()

msg = f'{len(contents):<{HEADERSIZE}}' + filename

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((args.address, args.port))
s.sendall(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
data = s.recv(128)
print(str(data, 'utf-8'))
if(data):
    s.sendall(contents)
    s.close()

print(bytes(msg,'utf-8'))
print(f'File size: {len(contents)}')
```

I have no idea where the bug is. I tried the same with the txt file and it lost some content at the and of the file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are expecting that every call to `client.recv(2048)` returns exactly 2048 bytes.  There is absolutely no reason for that to be true - the call will return whatever amount of data has been received so far, up to a *maximum* of 2048 bytes.  You need to advance `bSize` by the actual length of the received data (and stop when it *equals* the file size, it should never actually exceed it).

Comment: bSize is just a variable that closes the socket when it exceeds  the original file size. It has nothing to do with bytes that I am receiving. I've tried it with the endless loop too and the result is the same. f.write(client.recv(2048)) does the receiving and the writing the file inside the while True loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your file when closing the connection.

Here is a minimal working example, slightly updated from your code:

```py
import socket
import argparse
import os
import sys
import threading

HEADERSIZE = 10

def serve():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 20000))
    sock.listen(5)
    (client, addr) = sock.accept()
    fileSizeAndName = client.recv(128)
    if(fileSizeAndName):
        print("Received a connection from ", addr)
        fileSize = int(fileSizeAndName[:HEADERSIZE])
        fileName = str(fileSizeAndName[HEADERSIZE:], "utf-8")
        print(f'Incoming file: {fileName}, size: {fileSize} bytes')
        client.sendall(bytes("Header received", "utf-8"))
        bSize = 0
        print("Received a connection from ", addr)
        f = open(f'received/{fileName}','wb')
        #received_bytes = bytearray(client.recv(2048))
        while True:
            f.write(client.recv(2048))
            bSize += 2048
            if bSize > fileSize:
                f.close()
                sock.close()
                client.close()
                print("Received file:", str(os.path.getsize(f'received/{fileName}')) + ' bytes')
                sys.exit(0)

def client():
    filename = "foo"
    contents = b'\0' * 64000

    msg = f'{len(contents):<{HEADERSIZE}}' + filename

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 20000))
    s.sendall(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(128)
    print(str(data, 'utf-8'))
    if(data):
        s.sendall(contents)
        s.close()

    print(msg)
    print(f'File size: {len(contents)}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=serve).start()
    client()
```

Here, I send 64000 NUL bytes. If you remove the `f.close()` line you get the following output:

```
Received a connection from  ('127.0.0.1', 43812)
Incoming file: foo, size: 64000 bytes
Received a connection from  ('127.0.0.1', 43812)
Header received
64000     foo
File size: 64000
Received file: 61440 bytes
```

Now, with the `f.close()`.

```
Received a connection from  ('127.0.0.1', 43838)
Incoming file: foo, size: 64000 bytes
Header received
Received a connection from  ('127.0.0.1', 43838)
64000     foo
File size: 64000
Received file: 64000 bytes
```

This time the file save by the server as the right size.

Kind.